# Gii module generator doesn't generate some files

Tags: yii, gii

I expect Gii module generator generate for 'admin' as follows:

```
modules/admin/AdminModule.php
modules/admin/components
modules/admin/controllers/DefaultController.php
modules/admin/messages
modules/admin/models
modules/admin/views/default/index.php
modules/admin/views/layouts
```

but it just generate list below:

```
modules\admin\AdminModule.php
modules\admin\controllers\DefaultController.php
modules\admin\views\default\index.php
```

Why?
How could I make it generate rest of those?
My first list expectation is according to "Web Application Development with Yii and PHP by Jeffrey Winesett" book.

Comment: What did you let gii generate? What exactly do you want gii to generate? The empty directories `components`, `messages`, `models` and `layouts`? What's the benefit?

Comment: Looks to me like this is not an error. You can simply create the other directories by hand, if at all needed...

Comment: I wanna generate a simple module named 'admin'. The book says it should happen like first list (with empty folders).

Comment: Yes you right, I can do it by hands. but I still don't know why there is deference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book was published a while ago (possibly for v1.0), so things will have changed since. What you are running into may be a good example of that.

Answer (score 0):

IT appears that the missing items are folders without any content.  I may be wrong but it makes sense.

Best wishes.